# Find not existing values in excel between two columns

Tags: excel, find

I have two columns, let's say A1 - search value and column C1:C100, I need to find out if A1 Value exists in C1:C100 what command or how could I do that?

Comment: Is this related to programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think can be achieved with the vlookup function:

- http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set D1 = IF(C1=$A$1;1;0), then copy it all the way down to D100, and then check SUM(D1:D100), if it is 1, you found A1 in C column.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it exists with `MATCH`, when the value isnt found it gives an error. Capture that error with `ISERROR`, make the two outcomes make sense in your logic with `NOT`:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1;C$1:C$100;0)))
```

gives `TRUE` when found and `FALSE` when not found